# How to avoid error incrementing crosstab dataset when trying to add pivot in jasper studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, pivot, crosstab

I want to add a pivot (crosstab) in jasper report. When I add the pivot, I get an error when I download the file. I tried to debug with running the query and I don't have an error and I also try to debug with showing the parameter on the view, the parameter is show up without an error, I also try to show the result of query, and the data is show up.

So what is my problem? and how to fix my code?.

**detail band**

```
<detail>
    <band height="230">
        <crosstab>
            <reportElement x="167" y="30" width="200" height="200" uuid="b1977adf-e860-43cf-8940-fe4862f16621"/>
            <rowGroup name="KOMPETENSI1" width="60">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{KOMPETENSI}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="72845a66-f743-4f35-8091-02df93de67d0"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{KOMPETENSI1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
                <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="5792f3fa-1bb5-4134-91e1-b51918c05ec0"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total KOMPETENSI1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
            </rowGroup>
            <columnGroup name="TAHUN1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{TAHUN}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="fd89bbdf-eb6c-4c75-ab2c-9414ccd88458"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TAHUN1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="2d91db64-a9d7-43d3-b1c5-4c61412de5a1"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total TAHUN1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <columnGroup name="JOB1" height="20">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                    <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{JOB}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="6adc10a6-8c28-4d17-bc6d-32727f7a8805"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{JOB1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabColumnHeader>
                <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="fe8d03a8-5308-4845-b868-2b4cec45c2b5"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Total JOB1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
            </columnGroup>
            <measure name="LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.String">
                <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{LEVEL_JOB}]]></measureExpression>
            </measure>
            <measure name="LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.String">
                <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI}]]></measureExpression>
            </measure>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" uuid="0e4ec703-4f2c-4389-bb9b-02a7f8df230e"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" uuid="8f49c8dc-e172-4407-ba54-6aa077591235"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="TAHUN1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="78be64d3-2d78-411f-9d60-3b545311e376"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="47ac3c87-fee5-4e99-bade-9304180bdc2c"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="JOB1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" uuid="94604b9b-36f7-4572-8c24-c48a538503b8"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" uuid="8f2f6f73-049e-45ae-9d5b-fe55abad0c24"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="41785b14-fc8f-4c85-928b-0df8555ffcb5"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0cfec42f-0f33-46ff-9367-2c0c4978744c"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1" columnTotalGroup="TAHUN1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="1081fcf5-f921-47a0-89c0-923b9be4fd73"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0215fe30-2917-40a7-84d1-2cdac6216373"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
            <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="KOMPETENSI1" columnTotalGroup="JOB1">
                <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ba2855de-e2bf-4354-9c4f-67105912b4d7"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_JOB_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="202c0fa6-308b-4a7e-9656-33eea6859d89"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{LEVEL_KOMPETENSI_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </cellContents>
            </crosstabCell>
        </crosstab>
    </band>
</detail>
```

**Parameter definition:**

```
<parameter name="pPersonId" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="npp" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

**Query:**

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select CASE WHEN (JENJAB like 'SEVP') THEN '4' 
    WHEN (JENJAB like 'EVP') THEN '4' WHEN (JENJAB like 'SVP') THEN '4' 
    WHEN (JENJAB like 'SVP') THEN '4' WHEN (JENJAB like 'AVP') THEN '3' 
    WHEN (JENJAB like 'AVP') THEN '2' END AS LEVEL_JOB, kompetensi, 
    level_kompetensi, tahun, job from OL_ASSESSMENT_RESULT 
    where tahun in (select tahun from ( select distinct tahun  
    from OL_ASSESSMENT_RESULT order by tahun desc)  
    where ROWNUM <=3 ) and npp = $P{npp}]]>
</queryString>
```

**Field declaration:**

```
<field name="KOMPETENSI" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="LEVEL_JOB" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="LEVEL_KOMPETENSI" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="TAHUN" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="JOB" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

**Error:**

> JRRuntimeException: Error incrementing crosstab dataset
>     Caused by: JRException: **Crosstab data has already been
>   processed**

[image]

Comment: What is the error?,  $P{npp} in query is this defined?

Comment: @PetterFriberg sorry, i forget to add another parameter in the post.

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35549251/edit) the post and included the error description as well.

Comment: @PetterFriberg in my case, the jasper report doesn't show an error. I just get corrupt data when i tried to download. Do you have any clues to know how to show up an error from jasper studio?

Comment: What does corrupt data mean?... download??, errors are showed in the "Report State" panel.

Comment: @PetterFriberg i run my program using another application. When i try to build the file, i don't get any errors. So i don't know how to fix the code.

Comment: we need some errors otherwise we are just guessing.... what is the other application?, can you get a stacktrace from it...

Comment: @PetterFriberg i using adf framework. And i can't trace from it. Can you suggest me how to trace it?

Comment: off-topic request off-site resource : ).... use log4j or something similar... write it to file...

Comment: @PetterFriberg sorry, the error already show up. Please check the update post. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have put the pivot, `crosstab` in the `detail` band and are using the report datasource for the `crosstab`.

Hence, on every record in the datasource the report iterates the detail band, creating new crosstab that are using same datasource. This does not work and gives you error

> **JRException: Crosstab data has already been processed**

**Solution**

1. Move the crosstab to the `summary` or `title` band, completely
   remove the detail band.
2. Create a specific `subDataset` for the crosstab

Comment: Please can tell what is wrong if similar data set is used for both the report and the cross tab?

Comment: @BirhanNega depends on datasource if it is [rewindable](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRRewindableDataSource.html) you could rewind it... but normally you can not, you need to use another datasource.